# .htaccess - any query to index.php - problems with nginx

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, mod-rewrite

I thought that i have only apache on my server, but i see that nginx catches some query's before apache do...

my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

But when i go to url like

```
https://site.domain/folder/another/folder/file.png
```

I get 404 error, instead of result of my index.php-script!

I tried to change my nginx-config by many ways so it was in vain.

There is it:

```
server {
    server_name site.domain www.site.domain;
    charset off;
    index index.html index.php;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-resources/site.domain/*.conf;
    access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/site.domain.access.log;
    error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/site.domain.error.log notice;
    ssi on;
    return 301 https://$host:443$request_uri;
    set $root_path /var/www/www-root/data/www/site.domain;
    root $root_path;
    location / {
        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
        }
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
        }
        location / {
            try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
        }
    }
    location @fallback {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 /;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        access_log off;
    }
    listen 77.777.7.777:80;
}
server {
    server_name ege2018.top www.site.domain;
    ssl_certificate "/var/www/httpd-cert/www-root/site.domain_le1.crtca";
    ssl_certificate_key "/var/www/httpd-cert/www-root/site.domain_le1.key";
    ssl_ciphers EECDH:+AES256:-3DES:RSA+AES:!NULL:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam4096.pem;
    charset off;
    index index.html index.php;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-resources/site.domain/*.conf;
    access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/site.domain.access.log;
    error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/site.domain.error.log notice;
    ssi on;
    set $root_path /var/www/www-root/data/www/site.domain;
    root $root_path;
    location / {
        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
        }
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
        }
        location / {
            try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
        }
    }
    location @fallback {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 /;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        access_log off;
    }
    listen 77.777.7.777:443 ssl;
}
```

(I changed-to-hide domain name and server ip)

Please, help me to solve this problem, i hope it's possible just by editing nginx-config.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you got access to both nginx and Apache HTTPd logs? `tail -F` both log files while you access the URL. `@fallback` does indeed look like it sends the request to HTTPd if it cannot find it locally, does the request get to the HTTPd log? You may find that `index.php` isn't where HTTPd is expecting to find it.

Answer (score 0):

My bad! I changed-to-hide actually url, which i want to visit, but key was there.
The url was like

> site.domain/icons/...

And apache go to his own icons folder despite .htaccess instructions...

I touched apache config to solve this problem - commented alias for /icons/